# Touchscreen (RS232) with 14.04 Unity Desktop

Tags: drivers, touchscreen

A client of mine has several old PCs with a 19" touchscreen (kiosk systems). So far there was WindowsXP installed.

Now I made a clean Ubuntu 14.04 installation (Unity only, no other desktop). I need to mention, that this is the first time I'm working with Ubuntu. Please be patient with me - I'm a real novice. ;-)

Everything looks fine, except the Touchscreen does not work. The screen is connected to the serial port (ttys0). Hardware is working - a cat ttys0 shows that signals are coming from the screen.

Somehow the driver does not recognize the device. Tried all kind of settings that I found in different forums. I guess most were for older versions of Ubuntu. Anyway, nothing worked.

I don't have a specific driver for the touchscreen. Somehow I need to get it working with whatever driver that comes with Ubuntu. No fancy stuff - like multitouch - required.

I'm sure, there is a simple way to tell the standard input driver how to recognize the serial port.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Jörg

Answer (score 0):

I just used this site to download xinput_calibrator in the 'Touchscreen Input Calibrator" paragraph. Downloaded on my Panasonic CF-19 with Ubuntu 14.04 and WOW! It works much better than the Toughbook factory installed calibrator in Windows 7!  I'm still new to Linux so I'm using the GUI, and I will be using the stylus on this thing far more than I ever did with Windows...  Forget Windows, this OS is superior!

http://toughbook.wikispaces.com/Linux+on+a+CF-19

Now I just need to find a download that lets me bring up my virtual keyboard (the one I never used with windows cause it was never this accurate)...